# Angular undefined promise

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in Angular, and maybe I don't understand everything about promise, so...
I have a resource factory

```
.factory('Product',["$resource", function ($resource){
    var Resource = $resource(
        "/api/product/:product_id/",
        {product_id: '@id'},
        {
            query: {
                isArray: true,
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    var items = angular.fromJson(data);
                    return items.results;
                }
            },
            update: {
                method: "PUT", 
            }
        },
        {
            stripTrailingSlashes: false
        }
);
```

And in my other factory.

```
.factory('Get',["$http", "Product", function ($http, Product){
    return {
        getDesc: function(id){
            var allProducts = Product.query();
            var products = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < allProducts.length; i++){
                if(allProducts[i].desc == id){
                    products.push(allProducts[i]);
                }
            }
            return products;
        }
    }
}])
```

And in my Controller

```
 $scope.someClick = function(product){
        var products = Get.getDesc(product.id);
        products.$promise.then(function(data){
            $log.log(data);
        });
 };
```

And I got: Error: r.$promise is undefined
I don't know why. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. Specifically with the promise:
The query method returns a resource that contains in itself a $promise. so you can do one of the following:
1. Return the promise and do the processing, the filtering (more on that later) in the controller.
2. Use .then on the promise to do the filtering and return that promise:

```
getDesc: function(id){
        var allProductsPromise = Product.query().$promise;
        return allProductsPromise.then(function(response){
            var products = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                if(response[i].desc == id){
                    products.push(response[i]);
                }
            }
            return products;
        });
    }
```

The other issue I see is the double filtering. Since your query takes an id, I assume you get only the relevant product. Why do you have to filter the results (iterate and compare the id)? If my observation is correct, you might not need the filtering block and you can return directly the original promise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This filtering will be more complicated. For example first model has foreignKey to another model, and I will filter by this FK, etc.
PS. What if I need to filter other data in this factory using these earlier filtred data (Products)?

Comment: Basically, promises handlers are chained and used as filters/transformers. The returned value of the first handler is passed on to the next handler, and so on. This is why it is important to return a value at each handler.
Saying that, you could implement your login in handlers your append (before returning the promise).
Think about an order service. You get a base order and have to add various taxes and costs:
getPrice: function(){return Price.get().then(addCommision).then(addTax).then(addInsurance);
}.
The next handler (.then(myHandler) ) will see the composed price